# Qt creator 5 link

Tags: qt, linker, qt-creator, libpng

I have qtcreator 5 and I want to use the libpng12-0 library.
I don't know how I have to link into my project ?
There's a problem when I writte:

```
loadedimage = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());
```

I know that I have to writte something like:

```
     LIBS += -L
     LIBS += -libpng12-0
```

Does anyone know what I have to do ?

I tried a lot of things but I'm new on qt creator 5. Thanks for help.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: "-L" option is for specifying the library folder.

Comment: "-l" option is for specifying the library file (without lib prefix) : "-lpng12" for libpng12 linking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a GUI method then,

- Open .pro file
- Right click any where in text editor area
- Choose Add Library
- Then choose the type of library
- Provide the path of the library file
- Done.

If you directly want to edit .pro file, then library name will be `-lpng12-0` not `-libpng12-0` .

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the first method and it solved my problem !